# Hibernate ddl-auto: update @OneToOne working unexpected

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one

I'm using **ddl-auto: update** and along with **@OneToOne** mapping, I'm facing unexpected behavior. In below mention class TagCountryAdminEvaluationMapping, I'm expecting auto-generated **map_id** to be the primary key but **ddl-auto: update** creating primary key using **(tag_id, country_id)**(see the logs)

```
package com.myapp.model.dto;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ConstraintMode;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

import com.myapp.constant.Indicator;

@Entity @Cacheable
@Table(name = "map_tag_country_admin_evaluation")
@DynamicInsert(value=true)
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class TagCountryAdminEvaluationMapping implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3442004921950151844L;


    public TagCountryAdminEvaluationMapping() {
        super();
    }

    public TagCountryAdminEvaluationMapping(Tag tag, Country country, AdminEvaluation evaluation, Indicator status) {
        super();
        this.tag = tag;
        this.country = country;
        this.adminEvaluation = evaluation;
        this.status = status.getValue();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "map_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="tag_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id",
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "tag_fk", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    public Tag tag;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="country_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id",
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "country_fk", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    public Country country;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="admin_evaluation_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id",
    foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "eval_fk", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    public AdminEvaluation adminEvaluation;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private Long status;
}
```

Logs:-

```
01:10:52.137 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
Hibernate: create table map_tag_country_admin_evaluation (map_id bigint not null, status bigint not null, admin_evaluation_id bigint not null, country_id bigint not null, tag_id bigint not null auto_increment, primary key (tag_id, country_id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: alter table map_tag_country_admin_evaluation drop index UK_4vmcebk4n151u0ywr236qm4js
Hibernate: alter table map_tag_country_admin_evaluation add constraint UK_4vmcebk4n151u0ywr236qm4js unique (country_id)
Hibernate: alter table map_tag_country_admin_evaluation drop index UK_skii0njylqafa531cves8xj1
Hibernate: alter table map_tag_country_admin_evaluation add constraint UK_skii0njylqafa531cves8xj1 unique (map_id)
Hibernate: alter table map_tag_country_admin_evaluation add constraint FK9xolmrvve8a6hj4s5tbse9bv foreign key (country_id) references rd_country (id)
Hibernate: alter table map_tag_country_admin_evaluation add constraint FKgsu0c8bva325chdcbxuruhcqo foreign key (tag_id) references con_tag (id)
```

[image]

I'm just expecting **map_id** to be the primary key and all other values should be **NotNull**
and I have to use **ddl-auto: update**.
Can someone help me here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you remove all constraints from My sql UI and try running it? Because the logs generated shows correct about generayting foreign keys

Comment: That don't work. With ddl-auto: update, Sync and Updates everything as per the Model/Entity defined.